# Samsung phone won't turn on

Tags: samsung

A brand new `Samsung` phone, a 2017 A3 in this case turns off and is not turning back on.
The only workaround is to press "Power button + Volume Down Button" simultaneously for 10 seconds, but this keeps happening.

Comment: I suggest you rearrange the question and your own answer. Parts of the answer seem to belong in the question.

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

The phone is never actually turned off. It is just the screen that it is turned off. And it seems that there is no way to turn it on. BTW if you connect your device through `abd` you will verify that the device is indeed turned on.

## Why it happens

It seems that a ""feature"" that Samsung haven't devoted any time to test it is causing this. The feature is called something like:

> Avoid accidental screen awake when the phone is in your pockets or in your bag.

## When it happens

It happens when this feature is enabled, and then you leave your phone in a relatively dark room for some time ( >30mins perhaps).
Then it looks like this feature is putting the phone into a state where key presses on the power button or the home button are ignored.

## Solution

1. Reboot the phone

To do it hold <kbd>Power Button</kbd> + <kbd>Volumn Down</kbd> for 10 seconds, as `adb reboot` won't be working when the phone is in this state.

2. Once the device boots up disable that stupid "feature"